# circular convolution over Invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set of distinct vectors {$a,b,c,d,...$} in a subspace $C$ of $R^n$.

$C = \pi (C)$  where $\pi : R^n \rightarrow R^n$  defined by $\pi (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_2,...,x_n,x_1)$

How can I prove the following?

> For any two vectors $a$ and $b$ belong to $C$,  $a \circledast b \in C$ ($\circledast$ : circular convolution); if $C$ is invariant under $\pi$.

Comment: What is circular convolution?

Comment: The circular convolution, also known as cyclic convolution, of two aperiodic functions occurs when one of them is convolved in the normal way with a periodic summation of the other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write the standard basis vectors as $e_1,\dots,e_n$, with the cyclic convention that $e_{n+1}=e_1$, note that $\pi(e_i)=e_{i-1}$ and that $\pi$ is linear, so $\pi(\sum b_i e_i)=\sum b_{i+1}e_i$. By induction, $\pi^{\circ j}(\sum b_i e_i)=\sum b_{i+j} e_i$.
$c=a*b=\sum_{ij} a_j b_{i-j} e_i=\sum_j a_j (\sum_i b_{i-j} e_i)= \sum_j a_j \pi^{-\circ j}b$.